# Parent Vuetify VMenu Not Closing When Child Selected

Tags: vue.js, navigation, vuetify.js

My app creates it's main navigation dynamically via for loops to generated nested vmenu's and vlists.  It generates correctly.  The problem is when a user clicks a link in a nested menu, the parent menu remains open. I've tried close-on-click and close-on-content-click on both the main and nested menu, but that's not working.

My codepen has a simplified example.  If you select MENU 1, then hover over Subitem 1-1 and click on Subitem 1-1-1, that immediate menu closes, but the main menu remains open.

[My codepen](https://codepen.io/mdgreenleaf/pen/LMjEGp?editors=1011).

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <!-- top level menu -->
      <v-menu
        v-for="(menu,index) in menus"
        :key="`menu-${index}`"
        offset-y
        close-on-click
        @click="route()"
      >
        <v-btn
          flat
          primary
          slot="activator"
        >{{ menu.title }}</v-btn>
        <!-- each item on a menu  ..  is a menuitem -->
        <v-list dense>
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(menuitem,index) in menu.items"
            :key="`menuitem-${index}`"
            @click="route()"
          >
            <!-- or a popout of submenu items -->
            <v-list-tile-content>
              <v-menu
                offset-x
                open-on-hover
                close-on-click
              >
                <v-list-tile
                  slot="activator"
                  @click="route()"
                >
                  <v-list-tile-title>{{ menuitem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                  <v-list-tile-action
                    class="justify-end"
                    v-if="menuitem.items"
                  >
                    <v-icon primary>arrow_right</v-icon>
                  </v-list-tile-action>
                </v-list-tile>
                <v-list
                  dense
                  v-if="menuitem.items"
                >
                  <v-list-tile
                    v-for="(menusubitem,index) in menuitem.items"
                    :key="`menusubitem-${index}`"
                    @click="route()"
                  >
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{ menusubitem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                  </v-list-tile>
                </v-list>
              </v-menu>
            </v-list-tile-content>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

And the related script.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({    
    menus: [
      {
        title: 'MENU 1',
        items: [
          { title: 'Subitem 1-1',
            items: [

              { title: 'Subitem 1-1-1' },
              { title: 'Subitem 1-1-2' }
            ]
          },
          { title: 'Subitem 1-2' },
          { title: 'Subitem 1-3' }
        ]  
      },
      {
        title: 'MENU 2',
      },
      {
        title: 'MENU 3',
        items: [
          { title: 'Subitem 3-1' },
          { title: 'Subitem 3-2' },
        ]  
      }]
  }),
  methods: {
    route() {
      console.log("replace with router")
    } 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to access and close parent menu explicitly via `isActive` property:

```
route(parentMenuIndex) {
  if (arguments.length) {
      const parentMenu = this.$refs.menuRef[parentMenuIndex];
      parentMenu.isActive = false;
  }
}
```

where `this.$refs.menuRef` is used to access *parent* menu component via the [`ref` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements):

```
<v-menu
      v-for="(menu,index) in menus"
      :key="`menu-${index}`"
      offset-y
      close-on-click
      close-on-content-click
      ref="menuRef"
>
...
</v-menu>
```

Here is an [updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/GPONOQ?editors=1011)

Comment: Thanks.  When I run the updated codepen, it executes correctly for the first subitem, but not the second.  When looking at "parentMenu.isActive" in the click event method, it's always false on the second item.

Comment: @mdb, indeed, the incorrect index of parent menu has been passed for the second sub menu, codepen has been updated.

Comment: thanks, works on vuetify@2.5.4, tried using `:value` but no success.