# vuetify dropdown v-menu with submenu don't close on select

Tags: vue.js, drop-down-menu, vuetify.js, submenu

Working with Vuetify and have problem with the submenu to a a dropdown menu.
Everything works as it should, except for the main dropdown menu that does not closes when click on a submenu item. The submenu closes as it should.
1. The dropdown menu open on click
2. The submenu open on hover
3. If I click on a main menu item, the whole menu close. I want it to stay open as I don't have any router link for the main menu items, only for the submenu items.
4. If I click on a submenu item, I get routed to the new page, but the main menu does not close, only the submenu. Have to click a second time outside the dropdown box to close it.

I have tried with "close-on-click" and "close-on-content-click" without sucsess.

```
<v-menu offset-y :close-on-select="true">
    <v-btn flat slot="activator">
      <v-icon left>expand_more</v-icon>
      <span>Our Adventures</span>
    </v-btn>
    <v-list class="py-0">
      <v-list-tile>
        <router-link to="/adventures">
          <v-list-tile-title class="black--text plain-text">All our adventures</v-list-tile-title>
        </router-link>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
    <v-list v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" class="text-xs-left py-0">
      <v-menu offset-x right open-on-hover>
        <v-list-tile slot="activator">
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-list dense>
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="subItem in item.items"
            :key="subItem.title"
            @click="close"
            router
            :to="subItem.link"
          >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
```

and the related script

```
 items: [
    {
      title: "Nordic skating",
      items: [
        { title: "Open tour", link: "/adventures/skating/weekend" },
        { title: "Private tour", link: "/adventures/skating/private" }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Kayak",
      items: [
        { title: "Open tour", link: "/adventures/kayak/weekend" },
        { title: "Private tour", link: "/adventures/kayak/private" }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Hiking",
      items: [
        { title: "Open tour", link: "/adventures/hiking/eightdays" },
        { title: "Private tour", link: "/adventures/hiking/private" }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Cross country skiing",
      items: [
        { title: "Open tour", link: "/adventures/skiing/weekend" },
        { title: "Private tour", link: "/adventures/skiing/private" },
        {
          title: "Winter adventures",
          link: "/adventures/skiing/adventures"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved the issue of parentMenu not closing by using `ref` and the `isActive` property.

Steps:

1. Add `ref = "parentMenuRef"` to the parent `v-menu`
2. In the childMenu items, add `@click="$refs.parentMenuRef.isActive = false"`

This will close the parentMenu along with the childMenu when the childMenu item is clicked. [Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960121/parent-vuetify-vmenu-not-closing-when-child-selected)

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned Vuetify version, but I assume it's 1.x.
Here's what I have done in my projects:

- In top level `v-menu`, `close-on-content-click="true"`. This prop is true by default, so, you don't need to add it.
- The inner `v-menu` will have `open-on-hover`, which you code already has.
- Moved the slot="activator" to a template.
- On the activator of inner `v-menu`, I have added `@click.stop.prevent`

So, your code should look like:

```
<v-menu offset-y>
  <v-btn flat slot="activator">
    <v-icon left>expand_more</v-icon>
    <span>Our Adventures</span>
  </v-btn>
  <v-list class="py-0">
    <v-list-tile>
      <router-link to="/adventures">
        <v-list-tile-title class="black--text plain-text">All our adventures</v-list-tile-title>
      </router-link>
    </v-list-tile>
  </v-list>
  <v-list v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" class="text-xs-left py-0">
    <v-menu offset-x right open-on-hover>
      <template slot="activator">
        <v-list-tile 
          @click.stop.prevent
        >
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      <template>
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-tile
          v-for="subItem in item.items"
          :key="subItem.title"
          @click="close"
          router
          :to="subItem.link"
        >
          <v-list-tile-title>{{ subItem.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Side Note: `slot` attribute is deprecated in Vue 2.6. Please consider using `v-slot` directive. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now the main menu stays active even though I click an item. Thats good. But the dropdown main manu does not close when I chose an item in the submenu. Guess that I need some command in the v-list-tile for the submenu to close parentMenu on click.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "open-on-hover" then it will work as it should be. Open-on-hover gives effect close window on 2 time click. I had same issue and no success. I would suggest you to custom menu instead of Vuetify menu.